# I have some images of book pages want to convert it to text using OCR

Tags: ocr

Hello there I have book pages in images tiff format and I want to extract text from these pages into a text file but I am not getting the text as needed because the text in images is in cursive so it is difficult to convert them to text please anyone find me a solution for them to convert into the text. I have already tried many solutions online but none of them worked for me so please give me some resource that will be able to help me.

[image]

Comment: Please tell us what "many solutions online" were.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest first seeing if Google has already scanned the book for you.

Answer (score 0):

Logically it should be an easy task to perform OCR with known font. However I haven't heard of any software that would focus on this particular problem. Most OCR programs have generic algorithms to recognize any (or multiple) font(s).

Unfortunately the quality of recognition is somewhat proportional to the amount of money you pay for the software. Proprietary software seems to produce much better results. And freeware, no matter how much it's developers are bragging about it, fails quite often and suffers from low quality.

So if you are interested in getting good results, then get ready to pay good price for it.

By the way, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628994/ocr-for-known-font) on SO, covers exactly the same problem as yours. Answer by Andrew Cash there lists few decent programs.

I personally recommend ABBYY Lingvo, as I have used it myself and results ok.

Good luck